# problemas para validar con preg_match y filter_var

Tags: php, pdo

tengo un problema al tratar de validar input con **preg_match** y **filter_var** no me hace la validación esperada. Anexo el código a ver en que estoy fallando.

```
<?php
include_once "conexion/conexion.php";

if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){


$nombresyapellidos = $_POST['nombresyapellidos'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];


 if(strlen(trim($nombresyapellidos)) < 1 || strlen(trim($email)) < 1 || strlen(trim($user)) < 1 || strlen(trim($pass)) < 1 || strlen(trim($pass2)) < 1) 
 {
   $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: No pueden haber campos vacios. !";
 }

else if($_POST['pass']!=$_POST['pass2']) 
{ 
  $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: Las contraseñas deben coincidir. !";
} 

else if(strlen($pass) < 8)
{
  $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: La contraseña debe tener al menos 6 caracteres. !";
}

else if(strlen($pass) > 16)
{
  $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: La contraseña no puede tener más de 16 caracteres. !";
} 

else if (preg_match ("/^[a-z]+$/", $_POST['pass']))
{
  $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: La contraseña1 debe tener al menos una letra minúscula. !";
}

else if(preg_match("/^[A-Z]+$/", $_POST['pass']))
{
  $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: La contraseña2 debe tener al menos una letra mayúscula. !";
}

else if(preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $_POST['pass']))
{
  $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: La contraseña3 debe tener al menos un caracter numérico. !"; 
}

else if(preg_match("/^[\W]+$/", $_POST['pass']))
{
  $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: La contraseña4 debe tener al menos un caracter especial. !";  
}

else if (filter_var(($_POST['email']), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
{
  $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: Dirección de correo inválida. !";
}

else if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/", $_POST['nombresyapellidos']))
{
  $errMSG = "Este campo solo acepta letras.";
}

else{ 
    //si no hay errores continuo
```

Comment: "_preg_match y filter_var no me hace la validación esperada_". ¿Cómo no te hacen la validación esperada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás usando `preg_match` al revés. Según la [documentación de `preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php):

> **preg_match()** devuelve 1 si **`pattern`** coincide con el **`subject`** dado, 0 si no, o **FALSE** si ocurrió un error.

Teniendo eso en cuenta, por ejemplo, en esta condición que tienes:

```
if (preg_match ("/^[a-z]+$/", $_POST['pass']))
{
  $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: La contraseña1 debe tener al menos una letra minúscula. !";
}
```

Si se cumple el patrón en la contraseña, es decir, si hay al menos un carácter en minúsculas, entonces se va a mostrar el mensaje de error. Cuando debería ser al revés: si no se cumple el patrón, muestra el mensaje de error.

Y con `filter_var` ocurre lo mismo. Si vas a la [documentación de esa función](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-var.php), verás que si se devuelve algo quiere decir que es correcto... pero en la condición que tienes se considera incorrecto:

```
if (filter_var(($_POST['email']), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
{
  $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: Dirección de correo inválida. !";
}
```

Una solución rápida sería negar el resultado de esas funciones, o comprobar si son `false`.

Comment: gracias amigo por tu respuesta, lo he colocado así pero se me cae la web a la hora de la validación `else if(!filter_var(($_POST['email']), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: Dirección de correo inválida. !";
} else {
    echo "E-mail is valid";
}`